# Using right and righteous

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning-in-context, synonyms

In this song of 5FDP: *The wrong side of heaven and the righteous side of hell*

Why do they use *righteous* instead of *right*?

Is that the same thing, so you can use both, of have a different meaning on this case?

Is there a similar case to the *wrong* word?

Comment: I think it's meant to be a pun, or thought-provoking language. Poets and songwriters do that.

Comment: I thought this too... that's why I asked if it's a similar word or something that was needed in the phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, in a song, you will want to keep to the rhythm, the meter of the song. So that might be one reason to use righteous instead of right.

Then, righteous and right are related, righteous being descriptive of someone that does the right things. The right side of hell might not be the same as the place in hell were the righteous people are, but that might lead to a more theological or philosophical discussion than would be appropriate on this site :)

As for the "wrong" equivalent, you might be looking for "wicked" - it is often used as an antonym for righteous.

Comment: Great answer @oerkelens, I've tried so many times to understand that but got confused about the relation that the 2 words have. Thank you o/

Comment: Truly, a *righteous* answer. Not because it gives OP the correct answer, obviously, since that would just be an incorrect/whimsical usage. But with only a slight extension from the traditional theological sense, it's not unreasonable to say it's "righteous" to declare *philosophical discussion ... [in]appropriate on this site*.